# How to unit test methods with dependencies on other methods

Tags: java, junit5

I have the following method

```
public static File getInventoryFileFromProperties(){
    String filePath = getProperty(ConfigProperties.MY_INVENTORY_FILE);
    logger.debug("Looking for inventory file at {}", filePath);

    return new File(filePath);
}
```

How do i unit test this for the following condition, ConfigProperties.MY_INVENTORY_FILE is not present in the properties file.

```
getProperty() // gets values from property file
ConfigProperties.MY_INVENTORY_FILE // is an enum of keys
```

Comment: Can you modify `getInventoryFileFromProperties()` and the containing class to be more easily unit-testable or are you looking for ways to test the code as it is now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to make code that accesses external resources -- such as the file system -- unit testable, is by creating an *abstraction layer*, e.g.:

```
public class FileAccessor {        
    public String getProperty(ConfigProperties property) {
        // property file access code goes here
    }

    public File createFile(String filePath) {
        return new File(filePath);
    }        
}
```

Then, the class-under-test can be refactored to use the resource-accessor through *constructor injection* of the dependency:

```
public class ContainingClass {

    private FileAccessor fileAccessor;

    // this constructor is accessible for the unit tests
    ContainingClass(FileAccessor fileAccessor) {
        this.fileAccessor = fileAccessor;
    }

    // this constructor is used by normal client code
    public ContainingClass() {
        this(new FileAccessor());
    }

    public File getInventoryFileFromProperties(){
        String filePath = fileAccessor.getProperty(ConfigProperties.MY_INVENTORY_FILE);
        return fileAccessor.createFile(filePath);
    }
}
```

Finally, unit testing becomes simpler now that you can mock the file access. This test uses the [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/) mocking framework for mocking the dependency, and also works with earlier versions of JUnit:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ContainingClassTest {

    @Test
    public void getInventoryFileFromProperties_MY_INVENTORY_FILE_isMissing() {

        FileAccessor fileAccessor = mock(FileAccessor.class);

        // arrange the config file to return a null value for the property
        when(fileAccessor.getProperty(ConfigProperties.MY_INVENTORY_FILE)).thenReturn(null);

        // act; call the method
        new ContainingClass(fileAccessor).getInventoryFileFromProperties();

        // assert that the file-creating method was called with a null path
        verify(fileAccessor).createFile(isNull(String.class));
    }
}
```